# Using Pandas/Numpy input data for tensorflow hub layer that accepts one dimensional input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-hub

Good afternoon.  I'm trying to re-use an NNLM layer from tensorflow hub to do transfer learning for an NLP task.

I'm trying to get this started using the IMDB dataset.

The issue I'm running into is that many tensorflow hub NNLM layers come with the following caveat:  The module takes a batch of sentences in a 1-D tensor of strings as input.  Most of the examples I see out there are using pre-loaded datasets, but the vast majority of the data I work with is either stored in pandas or Numpy, so I'm trying to get the input data to work from this format.

The layer I'm trying to use can be found here:  https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-500/2

So far, I have tried the following without success.

**Approach 1:** Converting the pandas dataframe or numpy array into a tensorflow dataset object.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import pandas as pd
import numpy as n
from tensorflow import string
import tensorflow as tf

hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-500/2",
                       input_shape=[], dtype=string)
mod2 = Sequential([
  hub_layer,
  Dense(20, activation='relu'),
  Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

mod2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

And then I try and convert the training data as follows:

```
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_sequences, y_train.values))
```

`train_sequences` is a collection of reviews that have been tokenized, and are stored as a `(35000, 150)` shaped numpy array.

Then I call:

```
mod2.fit(train_data.batch(32).prefetch(1), epoch=2)
```

Which gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected keras_layer_input to have 1 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 150)
```

I get this error message regardless of the value passed into `batch()` or `prefetch()`, and regardless of whether or not I use the `steps_per_epoch` argument when I call `fit`.

I know this requires reshaping in some way, but I'm not familiar with tensorflow, and don't know how to do it for this particular task.

**Approach 2:** Create an iterator out of a numpy array.

My thinking is that if I turn a numpy array into an iterator, I could call `next()` on that, and incrementally feed each row into the layer from keras hub.

This is my code:

```
train_iter = iter(train_sequences)
y_iter     = iter(y.values)

a = next(train_iter)
b = next(y_iter)
```

Then I call:

```
mod2.fit(a, b, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=1)
```

And get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I know the basic idea is that I have to setup my input data so that it's the right shape for the layer, but how to do this escapes me at the moment.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't tokenize yourself. Just pass one string for each input that you want to embed.

Comment: @arnoegw You mean just pass in the raw text values?

Comment: Yeah, as seen in the example usage (first code block) on https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-500/2

Comment: @JonathanBechtel, Can you please confirm if your is resolved by trying arnoegw's suggestion? It is because we can specify it as an answer for the benefit of the community. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowSupport yes that was the correct answer!

Comment: @JonathanBechtel, I have added the Answer. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioning the Answer in this (Answer) section even though it is already present in the Comments Section, for the benefit of the Community.

Passing **`Raw Text Values`** instead of the **`Tokens`** (generated using **`Tokenizer`**) has resolved the issue.

Example code is shown below:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-500/2")
embeddings = embed(["cat is on the mat", "dog is in the fog"])
```

For more information, please refer [this link](https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-500/2) for more information.